# when use class structure, scipy.integrate.dblquad cannot transfer args

Tags: python, scipy

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate


class Debug:
    def func(self, x0, x1, t0, t1):
        x0 + x1 + t0 + t1        
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = Debug()
    value, err = integrate.dblquad(main.func, 1, 2, lambda x: x, lambda x: 2 * x, args=(1, 2))
    print(f"the value of integration is: {value}")
    print(f"the value of error is: {err}")
```

When I try to calculate integration like this, I always get an error like below:

[must be real number, not NoneType](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoA1x.png)

Could someone tell me how to fix it without changing class structure? If I leave out class structure, everything works fine. But when I add class structure, error comes out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have dealed with this by adding `return` in the defined function `func`. When I write `return x0 + x1 + t0 + t1`. It works well, seems I forgot `return`......